# Why is max_length being ignored in BinaryField?

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create an invite system to register users, which stores a md5 hashsum based on the object's ID. Here's how my model is defined:

```py
class Invite(TimestampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    _code = models.BinaryField(max_length=16, unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        invite = cls.objects.create()

        hash_obj = hashlib.md5()
        hash_obj.update(str(invite.id).encode('utf-8'))
        invite._code = hash_obj.digest()

        invite.save()
        return invite
```

Thus when I call `Invite.create()`, I see a row in the database that has a `_code` that is 16 characters long (e.g. `��#�"��Zo�n�%��V`).

The problem arises, however, when I adjust `max_length` to `2`. I expected Django to either throw an error or truncate the value to two bytes, but it did neither; I am still seeing 16 bytes in new rows. Yes, I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

What is going on here? This is a bit concerning that I can't limit the length at all. I assume it's defaulting to `50` but I have no idea why. Any thoughts are appreciated.

[BinaryField description here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

Comment: Maybe naive, but have you restarted your django application? Length validation has nothing to do with migrations, iirc.

Comment: What database are you using? SQLite doesn't care. If you want to enforce it on save, use `full_clean` method

Comment: @Javed I did restart, which had no effect. You are incorrect, running `makemigrations` created a migrations file when `max_length` was changed.

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I am using SQLite, which must be the source of my issue. I don't see how I would use `full_clean` here as I don't need to validate input.

Comment: Then you will have to write a custom validator to enforce length on save

Comment: @MattMcCarthy validation is being done on django side, maybe constaraint was added to database, but validation is done in django.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the `BinaryField` class, you will see that having max_length parameter will only add a validator to a field:

```py
class BinaryField(Field):
    description = _("Raw binary data")
    empty_values = [None, b'']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('editable', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.max_length is not None:
            self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(self.max_length))
```

Now, you go to the docs and search for how validators are run:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

Now you see, that if you're not using `ModelForm` you'll have to run validations by yourself:

> There are three steps involved in validating a model:
>
> Validate the model fields - Model.clean_fields()
>
> Validate the model as a whole - Model.clean()
>
> Validate the field uniqueness - Model.validate_unique()
>
> All three steps are performed when you call a model’s full_clean() method.
>   When you use a ModelForm, the call to is_valid() will perform these validation steps for all the fields that are included on the form. See the ModelForm documentation for more information.
>
> You should only need to call a model’s full_clean() method if you plan to handle validation errors yourself, or if you have excluded fields from the ModelForm that require validation.

So, as i said, it has nothing to do with migrations, you just have to call `full_clean` method (or just `clean_fields` one) or use `ModelForm` and call it's `is_valid()` method.

refs:

[BinaryField implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2232)

[How validators are run](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run)

[Validating models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)